# A result for all invertible matrices?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider some invertible $N\times N$ matrix $A$, let $B=A^{-1}$ and let $A_{\left[11,nn\right]}$ be the $\left(N-2\right)\times\left(N-2\right)$
matrix resulting from A after removing row and column 1 and row and
column $n \neq 1$. I have seen that in some special case the following equality
holds for $n \neq 1$:
$$
b_{11}b_{nn}-b_{n1}b_{1n}=\frac{\det A_{\left[11,nn\right]}}{\det A}
$$
Is this a general result for all invertible matrices?

Comment: I checked the $N=3$ case (the simplest one) and it's true in general. You can probably show the full result by using the minor expansion of the det.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this result is correct in general. Here is a proof.

Without loss of generality, we can take $n=2$. Partition $A$ and $B$ as
$$
A = \pmatrix{A_{11} & A_{12}\\ A_{21} & A_{22}}, \quad B = \pmatrix{B_{11} & B_{12}\\ B_{21} & B_{22}},
$$
where $A_{11}$ and $B_{11}$ have size $2 \times 2$. Because $BA = I$, we can deduce that
$$
\pmatrix{B_{11} & B_{12}\\ 0 & I_{N-2}} \pmatrix{A_{11} & A_{12}\\ A_{21} & A_{22}} = \pmatrix{I_2 & 0\\A_{21} & A_{22}}.
$$
Taking the determinant of both sides yields
$$
\det\pmatrix{B_{11} & B_{12}\\ 0 & I_{N-2}}\det \pmatrix{A_{11} & A_{12}\\ A_{21} & A_{22}} =\det \pmatrix{I_2 & 0\\A_{21} & A_{22}} \implies\\
\det(B_{11})\det(A) = \det(A_{22}) \implies\\
\det(B_{11}) = \frac{\det(A_{22})}{\det(A)},
$$
which is what we wanted to show.

Comment: Really cool, +1 ! I agree that you can set $n=2$... but when you write $I_{n-2}$, do you mean $I_{N-2}$? In any case, I checked the case $n=2,N=3$ and it works.

Comment: @Quillo Right, that should have been $N-2$; I've fixed it now.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thanks for this. Do you know what is an extension of this result to an expression for $b_{ik} b_{kj} - b_{ij} b_{kk}$ in terms of elements of $A$? I have asked this question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4251300/165163

Comment: @Andres I do not know of any such extension

Comment: @BenGrossmann Do you think that the result for case $N=3$ does not have some natural extension to $N>3$?

Comment: @Andres The expression for $N = 3$ is interesting. I'll think about it.

Comment: @Andres I don't think that there's anything simple, but I suspect that there is a result that can be seen with the help of [alternating tensor products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra#Linear_algebra).

Comment: @BenGrossmann Thank you!