# Determinant of product of matrix and nullspace

Tags: matrices, determinant, matrix-decomposition, pseudoinverse, schur-complement

Assume I have a symmetric, positive-definite matrix $S \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$. Assume that there is some matrix $L \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times p}$ that has full row-rank, i.e., has rank $n$ and where $L L^T = I$.

Define $N \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times p - n}$ as an orthogonal basis for the nullspace of $L$. From some numerical experiments, it seems that the following is true.

$$\det \left( N^T S N \right) = \det(S)\det \left( L S^{-1} L^T \right)$$

I'm not sure how to prove it as I can't figure out how to replace $N$ with $L$ or vice versa. It seems related to the Sherman-Morrison-Woodbury result but it seems like it is missing a few terms.

Comment: @shadow I have a suspicion that [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4245146/81360) kind of result is relevant

Comment: Thanks! I think that connection to the Schur complement / inverse of blocked matrix is an interesting direction to think about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your formula is correct.

From the information given, we can deduce that the block-matrix
$$
U = \pmatrix{L\\ N^T}
$$
is orthogonal (i.e. square with orthonormal rows/columns). Let $A$ denote the matrix $A = USU^T$ (noting that $U^T = U^{-1}$). We have
$$
A = USU^T = 
 \pmatrix{
LSL^T & LSN\\
N^TSL^T & N^TSN
} = \pmatrix{A_{11} & A_{12}\\ A_{21} & A_{22}}
$$
Let $B = A^{-1}$ We similarly have
$$
B = A^{-1} = (USU^T)^{-1} = U^TS^{-1}U =
\\  \pmatrix{
LS^{-1}L^T & LS^{-1}N\\
N^TS^{-1}L^T & N^TS^{-1}N
} = \pmatrix{B_{11} & B_{12}\\ B_{21} &B_{22}}.
$$
Now, following the logic of my [previous answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4245146/81360), we have
$$
\det(A_{22}) = \det(A)\det(B_{11}).
$$
On the other hand, we have
$$
\det(A) = \det(USU^T) = \det(U)\det(S)\det(U^{-1}) = \det(S).
$$
Putting everything together, we come to the conclusion that
$$
\det(N^TSN) = \det(S) \det(LS^{-1}L^T),
$$
which is what we wanted.